# Intent flags not Working while starting activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I tried using the below mentioned flags while starting the activity.
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
(used in separate intents)

But it does not work as intended.

Are there any special cases where these are used ?

I have already gone through many articles , everywhere people suggest of using the launch modes in the manifest .

But this is not I want. I want to know that why is it not working . What am I doing wrong.

This is my code.

```
intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Try this.finish(); post startActivity(intent) ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? Maybe your method of checking it is incorrect.

Comment: @Dexto : I am trying to learn about the different flags. There is not any particular requirement for which i need solution.

Comment: @miva2 : yes.. its not working . My code is simply this ---> 
                intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent); 
And I am using the below command to check the tasks and the activities it contains :
adb shell dumpsys activity activities | sed -En -e "/Stack #/p" -e "/Running activities/,/Run #0/p"

Comment: @NishantChauhan I never useed that command but the code looks fine. Try following a tutorial literally, every word, run the app normally and see if it works.

Comment: Post your manifest. In what code are you trying to launch `ActivityA`? Please explain why you think it is "not working". What is happening and what do you think should happen?